# while highlighting the found text in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0k49mg89/1/) where I have table with data and search text box.

If I search with the word it should get background color as red and its working fine... once we search and removed the text from the search text box the table is getting totally red it should not happen.

How can I solve this ?

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    _this = this;       
    $.each($("#ftz-table tbody tr"), function() {
        if(!($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)){
            $(this).css("background-color","red");
        }   
        else{
            //what to write here.....  
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you want to add a check there if your string actually has a length higher than 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this fiddle out, [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jo_Geek/0k49mg89/2/)

You have to run this code at each keyup first itself:

```
$.each($("#ftz-table tbody tr"), function() { 
   $(this).css('background-color','rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'); 
})
```

and you must `return` from the function if string is empty.

**Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").keyup(function() {
    _this = $(this);
    if (_this.val() == "") {
      $.each($("#ftz-table tbody tr"), function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)');
      })
      return;
    }
    $.each($("#ftz-table tbody tr"), function() {
      if (!($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
      } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)");
      }
    });
  });
  $("#calculate").click(function() {
    var number = 0;
    var total = 0;
    var max = 1;
    $("#ftz-table tbody tr td:nth-child(3)").each(function() {
      var value = $(this).text();
      if (value != "") {
        total = total + parseInt(value);
        number++;
        if (value > max) {
          max = value;
        }
      }
    });
    $("#average").text("Average: " + (total / number));
    $("#max").text("Maximum: " + max);
    alert($("#search").val());
  });
  $("#main-checkbox").change(function() {
    var status = this.checked;
    $(".child-checkbox").each(function() {
      this.checked = status;
    });
  });
  $(".child-checkbox").change(function() {
    if (this.checked == false) {
      $("#main-checkbox")[0].checked = false;
    }
    if ($(".child-checkbox:checked").length == $(".child-checkbox").length) {
      $("#main-checkbox")[0].checked = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  background-image: url("bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1920px 974px;
}
.main-container {
  border: 0px solid none;
  height: 974px;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: -16px;
  font-family: trebuchet ms;
}
.login-nav {
  border: 0px solid white;
  height: 35px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.header {
  border: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  height: 64px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  outline: 1px solid #394B61;
  outline-offset: -5px;
}
.login-nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 1px;
  font-family: trebuchet ms;
}
.banner {
  padding-top: 36px;
  border: 0px solid black;
  height: 162px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.banner h3 {
  padding-left: 32px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  font-family: century gothic;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.body-container {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  height: 550px;
}
.body-container div {
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.header img {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-family: trebuchet MS;
}
.body-container a {
  color: skyblue;
  font-family: trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.login-nav ul {
  float: right;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.login-nav a {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.login-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav-bar ul {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.nav-bar li a:hover {
  background-color: #486881;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.nav-bar li:after {
  content: "|";
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}
.nav-bar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: auto;
  color: skyblue;
  font-family: calibri;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.nav-bar ul li:first-child:after {
  content: "";
}
.nav-bar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}
.services-body-container {
  margin-top: 44px;
  font-family: trebuchet MS;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.services-body-container div {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.services-body-container div:first-child {
  width: 277px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.services-text-container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.services-body-container div img {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.services-body-container div:first-child ul {
  border-top: 1px solid #5E5F70;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5E5F70;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.services-body-container div:first-child ul a {
  color: skyblue;
}
.services-text-container p {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.services-text-container h3 {
  color: skyblue;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: trebuchet ms;
}
.services-text-container ul {
  color: white;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.services-text-container p a {
  color: skyblue;
}
.request-container {
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #10223A;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.request-container div {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#request-spacing {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
button {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #135E75;
  font-family: trebuchet ms;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  border-width: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
#footer-links {
  color: white;
}
#footer-links a {
  color: white;
}
.request-container div {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
#footer {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #D4DBF3;
  height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#effect {
  outline: 1px solid #1D2D46;
  outline-offset: -7px;
}
table {
  color: white;
  font-family: segoe ui;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: left;
}
.services-container {
  font-family: trebuchet MS;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  margin-top: 44px;
}
.table-search-container {
  width: 874px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.search-container {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.search-container input {
  height: 22px;
}
.services-table-container {
  height: 446px;
  width: 875px;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
.services-table-container table {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
table th:first-child {
  width: 55px;
}
table th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 202px;
}
table th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 92px;
}
table th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 290px;
}
table th:nth-child(5) {
  width: 240px;
}
.styled-box {
  border: 2px solid white;
}
.button-container button {
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-family: segoe ui;
  font-weight: normal;
}
table tr:last-child {
  height: 120px;
}
.element-align {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#average,
#max {
  padding-left: 80px;
  color: white;
  font-family: segoe ui;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="login-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="" target="_blank">Request a Quote |</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="" target="_blank">Client Login |</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="" target="_blank">Vehicle Export Portal</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="logo.png">
    <div class="nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="Task2.html">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT FTZWS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="services.html">OUR SERVICES</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">OUR CLIENTS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT US</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="effect" class="services-container">
    <div class="table-search-container">
      <div class="search-container">
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="search" />
      </div>
      <div class="services-table-container">
        <table id="ftz-table">
          <tr>
            <th>
              <input id="main-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" />
            </th>
            <th class="element-align">NAME</th>
            <th class="element-align">SCORE</th>
            <th class="element-align">EMAIL</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input class="child-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" />
            </td>
            <td id="element" class="element-align">Vijay Prakash</td>
            <td id="element" class="element-align">50</td>
            <td id="element" class="element-align">vijay@technovert.com</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input class="child-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" />
            </td>
            <td id="element" class="element-align">Sashi Pagadala</td>
            <td id="element" class="element-align">90</td>
            <td id="element" class="element-align">sashi@technovert.com</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" value="" />
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" value="" />
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" value="" />
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" value="" />
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" value="" />
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="button-container">
        <button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
        <span id="average"></span>
        <span id="max"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    Copyright ©2014 FTZ World Services. All Rights Reserved.
    <span id="footer-links">
    <a href="">Contact Us</a>  |
    <a href="">Request a Quote</a>
    </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you @Jones Vinoth Joseph..... i need to style that check boxes into plane check box with just border and no color for it. can you help

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking if the search field has any value. And all rows get highlighted because all rows contain `""`

```
$("#search").keyup(function() {
    _this = this;
    var inputValue = $(_this).val(); // extract in variable so we don't call for each row
    $.each($("#ftz-table tbody tr"), function() {
      // check if input string has any value before comparing values
      if (inputValue && $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
         $(this).css("background-color", "red");
      } else {
         $(this).css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)");
      }
    });
  });
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0k49mg89/7/)

Also the `if (_this.val == "")` does nothing. I assume you ment `_this.value` or `$(this).val()`. But with my solution you don't need that if at all